# Why <a> and <button> tags with identical css properties look different?

Tags: html

The question is so simple I'm amazed I'm still struggling with this. In the snippet below I set the css properties so that when inspecting elements the computed css properties are identical for both `a` and `button` elements, but still the text alignment differs.

```css
a,
button {
  appearance: button;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-border-image: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button">Click Me!</a>
```

Is this difference due to some default property of one of the elements which is not visible in the computed css properties list? I've studied the MDN and W3Schools without finding the answer.

EDIT: I know how to align the texts (e.g., with `line-height: 32px;`) but I'm interested to know **why** the elements in the snippet differ. I changed the original question a bit to reflect this.

EDIT 2: For those who are just searching for a solution to the alignment issue here are cleaned samples how to do the alignment using `line-height` and the `inline-flex` proposed in a few answers. It still remains unanswered why these fixes are needed.

```css
a,
button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lineheight-fix {
  background: lightgreen;
  /* line-height must be the height minus padding */
  line-height: calc(40px - 2 * 4px);
}

.flex-fix {
  background: lightgray;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
Original unaligned: <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button">Click Me!</a>
<br /><br />
Line-height fix: <button type="button" class="lineheight-fix">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button" class="lineheight-fix">Click Me!</a>
<br /><br />
Inline-flex fix: <button type="button" class="flex-fix">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button" class="flex-fix">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: I see the height is making a difference and so is the font-size. Interesting

Comment: In regards to **Edit 2**, `line-height` has a direct relationship with `font-size`, there's even an alternative notation in the shorthand property `font` -- ex. `font: 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'` the 1.2 means `line-height` is 1.2 times the `font-size` which is 2.4ch, which leaves .1ch above and below. By default text is vertically aligned at baseline (that isn't actually perfectly centered because of ascenders, descenders, etc.).  `inline-flex` is like `inline-table` in the sense how itself behaves in the "flow" (`inline`) and how it's contents behaves (`flex`). `inline` will sit next to each other.

Comment: Anyways, there are two properties of `<button>` and `<a>` that are in direct conflict with each other `align-items` and `box-sizing` once they coincide with each other you can't tell them apart when rendered to DOM, see [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72438628/2813224) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is useful put button without default styles with **all: unset** and change display inline-block to flex element.

```css
button,
a{
  all: unset;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor:pointer;
  
  appearance: button;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-border-image: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Button</button>
or
<a>Click Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add `display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;` to the css rule to vertically center the text:

(P.S.: You can erase a lot of the other settings you added - see below - they have no effect here)

```css
a,
button{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: This solves the alignment issue nicely but I'd still like to know why we need to use the flexbox here.

Answer (score 0):

### Line Height Solution

Before flexbox was a standard, we relied on `line-height` and `vertical-align`. `line-height` has a direct relationship with `font-size`, there's even an alternative notation in the shorthand property font -- ex.

**Figure I**

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}
```

The 1.2 means `line-height` is 1.2 times the `font-size` which makes it 2.4ch, which leaves 0.1ch above and below. By default text is vertically aligned at baseline (that isn't perfectly centered because of ascenders, descenders, etc.). Note, `line-height` isn't a factor unless the `font-size` is huge and the height of it's parent has been or close to being exceeded or there's more than one line of text.

This solution relies on a fixed height (there are ways around that but that goes beyond the scope of the OP) and the tag must be `inline` or `inline-block`. Set `line-height` and `height` at the same value, then set `vertical-align` to `middle`.

**Figure II**

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 2.5; /* Default font-size is 16px */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Flex Solution

This solution is possible because the `<button>` and `<a>` are flex containers when `display` is `flex` or `inline-flex`. Unlike a `<div>`, `<button>` and `<a>` have conflicting properties that **are not apparent until `flex` is used**. The default property of `align-items` is dormant until `<button>` or `<a>` has `flex` or `inline-flex` applied to them.

**Figure III** shows the original style of the anchor and button as well as the styles that replace them and/or added.

**Figure III**

| `<a>`nchor | `<button>` | Changes to Both |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `align-items: center` | `align-items: flex-start` | `justify-content: center;` `align-items: center;` |
| `box-sizing: content-box` | `box-sizing: border-box` | `box-sizing: border-box`<sup>❊</sup> |

<sup><sup>❊</sup>`border-box` is applied to everything, see **Figure IV**</sup>

What `align-items` does is that it stretches (without distorting) the buttons' content and it centers the text vertically. The anchor had the correct value of `center` but the button did not -- `flex-start` aligns content to the left. In addition to the flex properties is a ruleset that I had neglected to use earlier: `box-sizing`. `border-box` is the more suitable value since it calculates dimensions without accounting for padding and border-width -- the button has the correct default this time while the anchor needed it's value -- `content-box` changed -- having `content-box` meant that border-width and padding is accounted for.

`inline-flex` is like `inline-table` in the sense how itself behaves in the "flow" (inline) and how it's contents behaves (flex). Inline behavior causes tags to sit next to each other and width isn't 100% by default.

In conclusion, as illustrated in **Figure III**, the anchor and button each had conflicting values on critical properties causing drastic differences in size and positioning of content.

**Figure IV**

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Taming `<button>` Styles

You have to strip both tags of their defaults, then add back the styles and behavior that you'd like to keep or change, like `cursor: pointer` or `text-decoration: none`.

There are default styles not reflected in the computed styles of certain form controls -- [**normalize.css**](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) addresses them with the following ruleset:

**Figure V**

```css
button,
input,
select,
optgroup,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; 
  font-size: 100%; 
  line-height: 1.15; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

The properties that make the button so difficult to control is `font-family` (they have their own non-standard one) and `font-size` (it doesn't conform to default). Unlike normal tags, buttons will not inherit the font properties unless they are given `inherit` explicitly.

### Example A

**OP Line Height Version**

```css
a,
button {
  /* Behavior */
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* Dimensions */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: max-content;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0 0.85em;
  border: 0;

  /* Content */
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 2.5;

  /* Aesthetics */
  text-decoration: none;
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a>Click Me!</a>
```

### Example B

**OP Flex Version**

```css
a,
button {
  /* Behavior */
  display: inline-flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Dimensions */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
  border: 0;

  /* Content */
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;

  /* Aesthetics */
  text-decoration: none;
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a>Click Me!</a>
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

### Example C

**Fancy Flex Version**

```css
/* Global (Dimensions) */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Font Default (Content) */
html {
  font: 500 2ch/1.15 'Segoe UI'
}

.clk {
  /* Behavior */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Dimensions */
  min-width: max-content;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
  border: 0;
  
  /* Content */
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* Aesthetics */
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 0.0625em 0.0625em, 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 0.125em 0.5em, 
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
  text-shadow: .06em .06em 0 hsl(200 50% 30%);
}

.clk:hover,
.clk:focus {
  background: rgba(2, 129, 255, 0.05);
}

.clk:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #0053ba;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  color: #0053ba;
}

.clk:active {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='clk'>Link or Button?</a>
<button class='clk' type='button'>Link or Button?</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove height:40px and you should be all set

```css
a,
button {
  appearance: button;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-border-image: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a type="button">Click Me!</a>
```